# How to list directories and output in Bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, automation

I want to grab a list of directories inside a folder, and output the list into an executable, which uses them to run something.

Pretty much, this bash files requires a list of folders inside my `$directory`, which vary from `@sub1`, `@sub2`, `@sub3`, and sometimes go all the way up to 30.
All sub folders are appended with the `@` symbol.

Currently, I manually add the subfolders into my list, and is called with `-sub="$subs"`, where subs is defined above as
`subs="$directory/@sub1;$directory/@sub2;`... etc

I do need to maintain the same formatting for the output, as to keep with the way the executable is built.

What's the best way for automating this?
Sorry if its a bit odd, my first question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution: `find . -type d -name '@*' -print0 -maxdepth 1 | xargs -0 yourprog`

Empty folder to start with, a few folders called @subX, a file which we do not want.

```
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir @sub1
mkdir @sub2
mkdir @sub3
mkdir subway
touch testfile
cd \@sub2
touch bar
mkdir @test
cd ..
```

Finding things and either printing them to standard out, exec-ing something with them and similar can be done with `find`. Use this rather than trying to parse ls output.

First argument is which folder to search (e.g. `find .` for the current directory)

`-type d` filters to only directories (no files)

`-name '@*'` any match which starts with a @

`-print0` print the result to standard out.  -print will also work, but -print0 does special stuff in case of spaces etc.

`-maxdepth 1` Do not search subfolders)

Result of `find . -type d -name '@*' -print0 -maxdepth 1` in the setup from above:

```
./@sub1./@sub2./@sub3
```

Note, these are prefixed by ./ which may or not be an issue for you.

Also worth reading: find's -exec option and find ..... {} +;

Comment: With a little bit of changing around the output, it did work!
Thank you very much!
You've saved me many hours.